# IIS Expressでは問題ないが、サーバのIIS上でASP .NET COREでPostが実行できない。

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

ASP .NET COREでAjaxによるデータの受け渡しを行うため、そのコードの組み方を調べております。
そこで、下記のリンクのサンプルが非常に分かりやすかったため、ダウンロードしてサーバへデプロイしました。

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet-Core-Razor-Pages.aspx

LocalのIIS Expressではボタンを押すことで、Index.cshtml内の"OnPostGetTime"メソッドが確実に実行され、正常にPostが実行されているのを確認できます。
しかし、サーバ側のIIS8.5上にデプロイした場合、エラーが発生してPostがはじかれてしまうという問題が出てしまいます。

原因が分からず、サーバのIISでチェックすべき項目がありましたら、ご教授お願いしたいと思います。
なお、サーバ側の設定ですが、.NET Core用のアプリケーションプールを作成し、.NET CLRバージョンも「マネージコード無し」になっております。

状況としては下記です。

1. サーバ側の仕様：
   Windows 2012 R2
   IIS 8.5 + .NET CORE 2.1ランタイムを動作
2. クライアント側の開発環境：
   　Windows 10
   Visual studio 2017
3. IIS Express上でAjaxは正常に動作し、クライアント⇒Localサーバ側へPostが確実に実行される。
4. IIS 8.5上にデプロイすると、クライアント⇒サーバ側へのPostがはじかれ、下のような文字化けエラーが発生してしまう。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 事前に IIS のサーバーに ASP.NET Core モジュールはインストールしましたか？ どのようにデプロイしたのですか？(.NET Framework 版アプリのように簡単にはいきません)

Comment: エラーコード 404 の意味は分かってますか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。調べたところ、IIS8.5とIISでは、ajaxのURLの解釈が異なるのが原因のようでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメント欄でのアドバイスありがとうございました。

url: "/Index?handler=GetTime" の部分の解釈がIISのバージョンによって異なることが分かりました。
アプケーションのアドレスを `http://example.com/test/` とした場合、各々のバージョンによってurlが下記のように解釈されてしまいます。

- IIS Express
  `http://localhost:{ポート番号}/test/Index?handler=GetTime`
- IIS 8.5 (server 2012R2)
  `http://example.com/Index?handler=GetTime`
- IIS 10 (server 2016)
  `http://example.com/test/Index?handler=GetTime`

IIS8.5の場合、存在しないアドレスが指定されてしまうため、404エラーになるようです。IIS 10の場合は問題なく動きました。

対策としては下記のようにページのアドレスを追加することで解消できました。

```
url: window.location.href + 'Index?handler=GetTime',
```

Comment: IIS8.5 に問題があるわけではなくてデプロイのやり方に問題があるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: IIS Expressは別として、windows server2012と2016でデプロイのやり方は全く同じです。

Comment: Windows2012R2 IIS8.5において、アドレスを"Test"から別のアドレスに変えて、Http://example.com/hoge/hoge2/Index/にしてみましたが、絶対パスのUrlで指定しないと、やはり 1つ上のディレクトリと勘違いしてしまいます。http://example.com/hoge/Index?handler=GetTime という感じで。

Comment: url: "/Index?handler=GetTime" で / で始まるのはサイトルート相対パス（絶対パスと言う人もいる）なので、jQuery ajax で要求をかける際にブラウザのアドレスバーに表示された url が例えば ```https://example.com/xxx/yyy``` であれば、jQuery ajax が要求する url は ```https://example.com/Index?handler=GetTime``` になるはずです。そこはサーバーは関係なく、クライアント側だけ（ブラウザとスクリプトの url の設定）の話だと思うのですが。

Comment: むしろIIS8.5の動作が正しいようにみえるのですが、それぞれのサーバ側のログとかあります？実際にリクエストしたURLはどうやって確認しました？

Comment: 意図的に例外を発生させ、エラーメッセージに含まれているRedirect情報から抜き出しました。※文字化けの原因はWiindows serverから帰ってくるレスポンスのエンコードがUTF16になっていたため、変換して対処できました。

Comment: Win10 21H1でVS2019(16.11.2) +IIS Expressで試しましたが、IIS 8.5と同様な404エラーになりました。ルート(/)をtest/にルーティングするような設定をしていませんか？

Comment: 特にルーティングの設定はやってません。発行先を「\\\*******\Test」(******:サーバ名)とサーバの共有ディレクトリに発行する設定を入れると、自動的にIIS Expressでもlocalhost/Testになります。仮に発行先を「\\\*******\Test2」とすれば、連動してlocalhost/Test2になりますが。

Answer (score 0):

私もIIS8.5にて同じ現象を確認しました。
列挙しておきます。
ブラウザはChrome, firefox, Edgeいずれも同じ結果です。

1. .net core2.1+IIS 8.5 ⇒ 問題あり
2. .net core2.1+IIS 10 ⇒ 問題無し
3. .NET5 + IIS8.5 ⇒ 問題無し

Postだけにかぎらず、ajaxにおいては、.net core 2.1はIISバージョンとの組み合わせで大きく挙動が変わります。サポートが終了していますし、今後は.NET5に入れ替えることをオススメします。

Answer (score 0):

質問者さんの回答のコメントで以下のように書きましたが、画像などが無いと説得力がなさそうなので、回答欄で画像を含めて説明します。回答ではありませんが、回答欄でないと画像が貼れないようなのでご容赦ください。

> url: "/Index?handler=GetTime" で / で始まるのはサイトルート相対パス（絶対パスと言う人もいる）なので、jQuery ajax で要求をかける際にブラウザのアドレスバーに表示された url が例えば `https://example.com/xxx/yyy` であれば、jQuery ajax が要求する url は `https://example.com/Index?handler=GetTime` になるはずです。そこはサーバーは関係なく、クライアント側だけ（ブラウザとスクリプトの url の設定）の話だと思うのですが。

具体例を画像を貼って説明します。

ブラウザ上でのページの表示は以下のようになっています。アドレスバーの url に注目してください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このページには以下のような jQuery ajax のコードが含まれています。url: "/Ajax/Details" とサイトルート相対パスになっているところに注目。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

button1 クリックで jQuery ajax による POST 要求をかけると `https://<ホスト名>/Ajax/Details` で要求が出ていきます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

質問者さんのケース `http://example.com/xxx/yyy` と url: "/Index?handler=GetTime" では IIS 8.5 での結果の `https://example.com/Index?handler=GetTime` になるはずで、IIS Express や　IIS 10 のように要求 url に test が追加されるというのは不思議です。

なので、質問者さんの設定・デプロイのやり方の問題ではないかと思った次第です。自分は IIS 8.5 の環境が無くて試せてないので想像の域を出ないですが。

Comment: 分かりやすいご説明、大変にありがとうございます。私は意図的に例外発生させ、.failで得たエラーを拾って確認してましたが、そうやって確認できるんですね。

Comment: IISのバージョンでアドレスが違うのもおかしいと思うので、もう少し調べてみます。でも、他でも同じ挙動が出ているようですね。

Comment: 一旦、ここは暫定的にwindow.location.hrefを付加することで凌ぎたいと思います。

Comment: 解決扱いになっていますが、URLを指定する場合は、@Url.Content("~/Ajax/Details") のような感じで指定するのが良いと思います。